# Using an iPod / iPhone in a 2005 BMW 525i Sedan

Tags: electrical, bmw, audio

I just purchased a BMW 525i (2005 model, automatic) and was wondering if this model supports an adapter like later models for an auxiliary or iPod cable integration? I did some Googling and found some people saying they have, but could find no reference to part numbers or instructions for doing so.

I found an adapter on eBay for $20AUD for BMW iPod integration, however I am not sure if the adapter is for later model BMW's 2007 onwards that I know support it. Here is a link to the eBay listing with the lead, would this work? http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/BMW-MINI-IPOD-IPHONE-USB-AUX-CABLE-CONNECTOR-ADAPTER-/230606087956?pt=AU_Car_Parts_Accessories&hash=item35b131a714

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used several of the products from [Dension](http://www.dension.com/) including the Gateway 300, Five and Blue.  For your car they list the Gateway 500.  This device is around $450, plus another $150 if you want to do bluetooth.  The ipod cable tends to be extra as well, though I don't remember how much.  Note that there are some caveats for your car, see their compatibility page for the Gateway 500.

These devices will also play audio off USB mass storage devices.  That's mostly what I use them for, though recently I upgraded to one that will do Bluetooth phone audio and music.

Their products are solid, in general though for playing USB it requires a Windows program to generate an index for the music to get the full functionality.  Their products are also kind of all over the map, for example the 300 I started with worked very reliably.  The more recently introduced Five requires steering-wheel audio controls, which my car does not have.  They wouldn't answer me about why they didn't make it so that you could use the head unit controls like the 300 does.  So I switched to the Blue, which doesn't require the steering wheel controls, but also doesn't display song titles on the car displays like the 300 and Five do -- again for no reason I could figure out.

Another option I have heard of is from [Mobridge](http://mobridge.us/).  I have never used these units, but my installer is in love with them (they need to get a room :-).  However, these are quite a bit more expensive than the Dension units, from what I could see, around 50% more.

I have purchased the Dension gear from [Enfig Car Stereo](http://enfigcarstereo.com/), and have been happy with them.  I found them by using the Dension compatibility matrix to look up the exact product code I needed, and then putting that into google and clicking on the "Shopping" section to find vendors.

Disclaimer: I have no relation to the above companies except as a consumer of their goods.